# How to have local secrets in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

If I have a local DB connection string I want to use, which is different from shared development connection string in source control, which is again different from the strings used in azure staging or prod, how can I apply this without requiring changes to files under source control?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as there is a documentation section about such case. If you still have any problems please modify your question with more specific details.